# Xamarin.Forms.Maps does not load

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Working with maps on my xamarin forms project and when i start the simulator i get the map when it is zoomed out, but when i click a button (that moves the map closer, zooms it in) the map doesnt load, it remains gray. The simulator I am using is iPhone 6s. If I however use the iPad Air simulator, it works just fine and the map loads when it gets more zoomed in.

When I deploy the app on my phone it remains gray as well. If I zoom out again, then it loads, but if i go futher in into the map then it turns gray again.

I use Location always in usage + when in usage and the standard iOS map.
I use version 2.1.0.6529 on both Xamarin.Forms.Maps as well as Xamarin.Forms in my mainfolder and the iOS folder. (Latest version)

I have "Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init();" in my appdelegate.cs file as well as some other code (push notifications), might that interfere somehow?

I am very confused what the issue might be.

Comment: What happens if you run the Xamarin's **Working with Maps** sample? Can you zoom in/out/.... If so, the odds are it is code related in your project and you will need to debug it and post some code of the problem area...   https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithMaps/

Comment: Solved it. Apparently it did not like when I changed maptypes together with the distance.